# SQL Select MAX w/ Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

```
SELECT a.first, a.last, b.number, c.last_login
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.first = b.first AND a.last = b.last
LEFT JOIN Table3 c ON b.number = c.number
```

Sometimes their are multiple entries for the number and I need to only select the max number from table b, however, when i try

```
SELECT a.first, a.last, MAX(b.number), c.last_login
```

I get an error. What can I do to select the maximum b.number?

Comment: try adding a group by:

GROUP BY a.first, a.last, c.last_login

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : Many years I haven't done SQLServer, but maybe the Analytic function can do the trick

```
SELECT v.first, v.last, c.number, c.last_login
FROM (
    SELECT a.first, a.last, LAST_VALUE(b.number) OVER (PARTITION BY a.first, a.last ORDER BY a.first, a.last, b.number) AS yourmax
    FROM Table1 a
    LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.first = b.first AND a.last = b.last
    GROUP BY a.first, a.last
) v
INNER JOIN Table3 c ON v.yourmax = c.number
```

Can you confirm this? I haven't sqlserver, but on oracle the MAX() OVER (...) exists. 
LAST_VALUE isn't the only keyword applying to OVER analitics

Answer (score 0):

If you want the max number you can use

```
SELECT a.first, a.last, b.MaxNumber, c.last_login
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN (select tmp.first, tmp.last, max(tmp.number) MaxNumber from Table2 tmp
group by tmp.first, tmp.last
) b
ON a.first = b.first AND a.last = b.last
LEFT JOIN Table3 c ON b.MaxNumber = c.number
```